# Problems uploading logstash 1.1.15 - monolithic jar as a Cloud foundry app.

Tags: exception, elasticsearch, cloud-foundry, vmc, logstash

When I run vmc update logstash. I get errors.

Uploading Application:
  Checking for available resources: OK
  Processing resources: OK
  Packing application: OK 
  Uploading (55M): OK
HTTP exception: RestClient::RequestTimeout:Request Timeout

Has anyone successfully pushed logstash to cloud foundry (Not Micro).

Answer (score 1):

Logstash is a standalone app (jar) which requires jruby. Cloudfoundry supports jruby within a war, but not yet in a standalone runtime environment.